# Bootstrap table won't sort

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I am creating a bootstrap 4 table like this:

```
dataElement = $('<table id="' + questionID + 'table" data-toggle="table">');
dataElement.bootstrapTable({
    url: "api/eval/getAnswersToQuestion.php",
    method: "post",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    queryParams: function(params){
        params["questionID"] = questionID;
        return params;
    },
    sortable: true,
    sortName: questionID,
    columns: [
        {
            field: 'token',
            title: 'Answer token'
        },
        {
            field: questionID,
            title: 'Answer',
            sortable: true
        }
    ]
});
```

It will sort the second column descending by default. However, it's not possible to click the table header in order to change the sorting order. What did I miss? In the corresponding [example](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#options/table-sortable.html#view-source) it's done like this.

Comment: Hi Luke, can you show us all the code?

Comment: I've figured the root of the problem myself just this very moment. But still thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table has not been added to the DOM yet. You're creating a new `table` node in the first line of your snippet, and call the `bootstrapTable` on that node on the next line. Which is perfectly fine, the node will be displayed correctly, but it won't be interactive (e.g. sorting won't work).

In order for the bootstrap table to work correctly, make sure the node is already existent in the DOM when the `bootstrapTable` method is called. This is because bootstrap table wants to transform the table node into the bootstrap table structure, which doesn't work outside the DOM.